# Best practices when using PHP with Firebird or Interbase

Tags: php, transactions, connection, firebird

The documentation for php-interbase is good - but not complete.  In particular, there's no complete examples for working with Firebird.  So how would you do it?

Comment: ...is this a question?

Comment: Please rephrase this as a question, and post the rest as an answer to your own question. It might even be better to split it up into multiple questions, as you are addressing at least three distinct points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic guidelines.

1. Choosing between ibase_connect() vs ibase_pconnect() - the less time connections are active the less possible conflicts and the easier maintenance & backups can be performed. Unless connecting to the database is "expensive" in terms of processing time (you're performing large amounts of real-time reads/writes) use ibase_connect() as needed.
2. Always use explicit transactions. Always. It's simple - assume every call to ibase_prepare() or ibase_query() requires a transaction handle - never a "raw" connection handle.
3. Always follow a transaction with either a ibase_commit() or a ibase_rollback() as appropriate.

Basic template for a read operation:

```
// These would normally come from an include file...
$db_path = '/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/MyDatabase.fdb';
$db_user = 'SYSDBA';
$db_pass = 'masterkey';

// use php error handling
try {
    $dbh = ibase_connect( $db_path, $db_user, $db_pass );
    // Failure to connect 
    if ( !$dbh ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Failed to connect to database because: ' . ibase_errmsg(), ibase_errcode() );
    }

    $th = ibase_trans( $dbh, IBASE_READ+IBASE_COMMITTED+IBASE_REC_NO_VERSION);
    if ( !$th ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Unable to create new transaction because: ' . ibase_errmsg(), ibase_errcode() );
    }

    $qs = 'select FIELD1, FIELD2, from SOMETABLE order by FIELD1';
    $qh = ibase_query( $th, $qs );

    if ( !$qh ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Unable to process query because: ' . ibase_errmsg(), ibase_errcode() );
    }

    $rows = array();
    while ( $row = ibase_fetch_object( $qh ) ) {
        $rows[] = $row->NODE;
    }

    // $rows[] now holds results. If there were any.

    // Even though nothing was changed the transaction must be
    // closed. Commit vs Rollback - question of style, but Commit
    // is encouraged. And there shouldn't <gasp>used the S word</gasp>
    // be an error for a read-only commit...

    if ( !ibase_commit( $th ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Unable to commit transaction because: ' . ibase_errmsg(), ibase_errcode() );
    }

    // Good form would dictate error traps for these next two...
    // ...but these are the least likely to break...
    // and my fingers are getting tired.
    // Release PHP memory for the result set, and formally
    // close the database connection.
    ibase_free_result( $qh );
    ibase_close( $dbh );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Caught exception: $e\n";
}

// do whatever you need to do with rows[] here...
```